# If $x=\frac{4ab}{a+b}$, then $\frac{x+2a}{x-2a}+\frac{x+2b}{x-2b}=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $x=\dfrac{4ab}{a+b}$,then we have to prove that $\dfrac{x+2a}{x-2a}+\dfrac{x+2b}{x-2b}=2$,$a\neq b$

The converse is easier to prove.Once we prove the converse,we can reverse the steps to prove the above,but the steps will look too magical.To prove the converse,we  take $\dfrac{x+2b}{x-2b}$   to the right and do some algebraic manipulation,then use componendo-dividendo and  find the value of $x$.However,I cannot see how to find the value of the second expression given the value of $x$.Some help will be appreciated.

**DETAILS:** This is a problem from a chapter named "Algebraic ratio and  proportion".This chapter deals with componendo-dividendo ,componendo,dividendo,addendo-dividendo etc. .

Comment: There must be an error or typo. Take $a=2, b=1$. Then $x=8$ and first fraction is 3, the second $\frac{5}{3}$, and the sum $\frac{14}{3} \ne 2$.

Comment: @grammatester,I think the denominator is $a+b$.

Answer (score 2):

$x=\dfrac{4ab}{a+b} \implies \dfrac x {2a} = \dfrac {2b} {a+b} \;\; and \;\; \dfrac x {2b} = \dfrac {2a}{a+b}  $

Therefore using the Componendo and dividendo method, $$\dfrac{x+ 2a}{x-2a} = \dfrac{3b + a}{b - a} \;\; and \;\;  \dfrac{x+ 2b}{x-2b} = \dfrac{3a + b}{a - b}$$

Therefore the LHS of your expression is equal to $$\dfrac{3b + a}{b-a} + \dfrac{3a + b}{a - b} = \dfrac{2(a - b)}{a - b} = 2$$ as long as $a\neq b$.

But please note we have assumed $a, b \neq 0$. If either one of them is zero the expression for $x$ becomes trivial. The proof consequentially easy.

Answer (score 0):

Simply substitute x and get:
$$\frac{x+2a}{x-2a}+\frac{x+2b}{x-2b}
=\frac{\frac{4ab}{a+b}+2a}{\frac{4ab}{a+b}-2a}+\frac{\frac{4ab}{a+b}+2b}{\frac{4ab}{a+b}-2b}\\
=\frac{2a(3b+a)/(b+a)}{-2a(a-b)/(b+a)} + \frac{2b(3a+b)/(b+a)}{2b(a-b)/(b+a)}\\
=-\frac{3b+a}{a-b} + \frac{3a+b}{a-b}\\
= \frac{-3b - a +3a + b}{a-b}
= \frac{-2b + 2a}{a-b} = 2
$$

Comment: I have found another way.$\dfrac{x}{2a}=\dfrac{2b}{a+b}$.Using componendo dividendo gives $\dfrac{x+2a}{x-2a}=\dfrac{3b+a}{b-a}$.Similarly,$\dfrac{x+2b}{x-2b}=-\dfrac{3a+b}{b-a}$.Adding them gives us 2.